# Keeping date/time values consistent when converting UNIX timestamps to .Net DateTime and back

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need to convert a unix TimeStamp to a .Net DateTIme value and vice versa.
This would be no problem, but I need to store the converted value as Int64 (Which means I lose the decimal places).

Losing the decimal places means I can get differences between the original and converted value. 
I would change the implementation and store the value as Double instead of Int64 if I could…but sadly I can’t (specification etc..).

**Edit:**
I need to store the value as Int64 representing the seconds since 1970 (unix timestamp)

I think I’ve found a work around for this problem but I’m not sure if it works 100%. (It worked 100% in my tests). Rounding the Double value before casting into an int seams to solve the problem.

Does this solve the problem or not?

Here is my code:

```
[Test]
public void ConvertTest()
{
    const Int64 orignalUnixValue = 252000596321;
    var referenceTimeZero = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    //Test 1
    var convertedDateTime = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(orignalUnixValue);
    var convertedUnixValue = (convertedDateTime - referenceTimeZero).TotalSeconds;
    var convertedDateTime2 = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(convertedUnixValue);

    //This works
    convertedDateTime2.Should()
                      .Be( convertedDateTime );

    //Test 2
    convertedDateTime = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(orignalUnixValue);
    var convertedUnixValueCasted = (Int64)(convertedDateTime - referenceTimeZero).TotalSeconds;
    convertedDateTime2 = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(convertedUnixValueCasted);

    //Difference of 1 second
    convertedDateTime2.Should()
                      .Be(convertedDateTime);

    //Test 3
    convertedDateTime = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(orignalUnixValue);
    convertedUnixValueCasted = (Int64)Math.Ceiling((convertedDateTime - referenceTimeZero).TotalSeconds);
    convertedDateTime2 = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(convertedUnixValueCasted);

    //Possible workaround - works for this example
    convertedDateTime2.Should()
                      .Be(convertedDateTime);
}
```

The first tests shows the correct way of converting the values, the second shows the current implementation and the third contains my workaround.

Comment: It sounds like your question should be "converting between DateTime and Int64 without losing information". The unix timestamp part sounds irrelevant...

Comment: Let's talk about your business requirements. During the lifetime of your timestamp/DateTime data, can it, at any point, contain decimal places/fractions of a second that are important and should not be lost?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Maybe this would be a better title.

Comment: @Dmytro Shevchenko As you can see from my example it can happen. Important is such a strong word... it would be good if application would not lose the second but it should still work with such a small difference.

Comment: @musium it's not the seconds that you can *lose*. It's the fractions of a second that are represented by the fractional part of the UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @Dmytro Shevchenko Yes but it results in the loss of a second
convertedDateTime2 has a value of: 01.08.9955 13:38:40
convertedDateTime  has a value of: 01.08.9955 13:38:41

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please look at my answer and share your thoughts as to why the conversion error is happening?

Comment: If you just want to store a `DateTime` value as an `Int64` with no loss of precision, just use the `Ticks` property (assuming you know which `Kind` to use).

Comment: @JonSkeet I can’t do this… I need to store the value as seconds since 1970

Comment: @musium: Then that should be in the question. You've currently said "This would be no problem, but I need to store the converted value as Int64" - that's what my suggestion does. It's pretty unclear what the requirements are (at least to me) - particularly in terms of whether you need any subsecond values.

Comment: Also, what value do you expect 252000596321 to represent? As seconds, it represents 9955AD... do you definitely need to store values as far ahead as that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I’ve added this to the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I used a range of random values to test my code and 252000596321 was one of the values. I posted this value to show the problem. My application properly never needs to handle values that big, but it could happen (at least according to the spec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

If you absolutely have to work with these values as with UNIX timestamp, then instead of `Math.Ceiling` I recommend using `Math.Round`. This way you ensure that the number is rounded to the *closest* integer.

Though, as suggested by Jon, it makes much more sense to use [`TimeSpan.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`, since ticks are `Int64` to begin with. You will have no conversion error this way.

---

## Explanation

It seems that the problem you're seeing is caused by the way `double` is stored and then by what happens when casting `double` to `long`.

I have modified your code a bit:

```
const Int64 orignalUnixValue = 252000596321;
DateTime referenceTimeZero = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

DateTime convertedDateTime = referenceTimeZero.AddSeconds(orignalUnixValue);
double convertedUnixValue = (convertedDateTime - referenceTimeZero).TotalSeconds;

Console.WriteLine(convertedUnixValue); // 252000596321
Console.WriteLine((long)convertedUnixValue); // 252000596320
```

As you see, the `double` variable *seems* to store the right value. But then there's some sort of a conversion error when casting to `long`.

By using Jon Skeet's [DoubleConverter](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs), it's possible to see that the variable's value is actually smaller than `252000596321`, which is the cause of the conversion error.

```
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(convertedUnixValue));
// 252000596320.999969482421875
```

Comment: Well you've got arithmetic happening here too - you've got division by "ticks per second" in the `TotalSeconds` part... It would take a fair time to work out exactly what's going on, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, but the value stored in the `double` variable is printed properly (in my first code sample). How come it is not *converted* properly? What's different here in how .NET is handling `double` for these two operations?

Comment: I'd have to look at it in more detail to work out exactly. You can use my `DoubleConverter` class to find out the *exact* value of a `double` though - download it at http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs and then use `DoubleConvert.ToExactString(d)` to get the *exact* value of `d` as a string.

Comment: @JonSkeet the exact value of the double is `252000596320.999969482421875`. Which explains what happens when casting to `long`. Do you think using `Math.Ceiling` is appropriate here? Or is possible for a `double` to store something like `252000596321.0000000001`, which would cause a similar problem when rounding up?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment, I'd use the `Ticks` property to start with. There's really no need to use floating point here.

Comment: Well I would need to divide the total ticks to get the numer of seconds since 1970…which would result in a double again. Btw. You can see the exact value of the double in the debugger.

Comment: @musium I modified my answer. Now it includes two possible ways of solving your problem. Pick one of them.

Comment: Looks like I need to use _Math.Round_. Thank you very much for your help!